# Guava EventBus - before and after subscribe method

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

I would like to have two methods automatically invoked before and after subscribe method like in example: (like JUnit @Before @After)

```
class SomeSubscriber {

 public void before() {
    // ...
 }

 @Subscribe 
 public void run(SomeEvent e) {
    // ...
 }

 public void after() {
    // ...
 }
}
```

Could you point me to right direction to resolve it?

Comment: If you use spring you could go with AOP: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: Spring AOP not working with @Subscriber annotation